# How to change filename on Dropzone Upload?

Tags: javascript, dropzone

I have the next code:

```
this.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {
    file.name = file.name + new Date().getTime();
    alert(file.name);
```

I need to concat datetime foreach file so every file has a unique name on the Front End. 
However this alert is returning the original name:

Actual Return: "fileName.png"
Wanted Return: "fileName-2/03/2020-10:26:32"

What im doing wrong?

---

Im trying like this:

```
            renameFilename: function (file) {
            let newName = new Date().getTime() + '_' + file; 
            file = newName;
            return file;
        },

        init: function () {
```

This is on the properties, and when i use alert(file) inside the statement works fine, returns: 12312354_filename.

however the filename is not changed as parameter in the other dropzone methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropzone configuration is well explained [here](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-renameFile)

`renameFilename` is **deprecated**.

You can use `renameFile` instead.

```
renameFilename: function (file) {
            file.name= new Date().getTime() + '_' + file.name; 
           }
```

You will still have actual **file name**, which can be accessed using `file.upload.filename`

Comment: Please note to actually use this answer as `renameFile: function(file) { return file.name; }` instead of using `renameFilename`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on 5.2.0 for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var CountFiles = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var Drop1 = new Dropzone("div#myPrincipalDropzone", { url: "/Article/UploadFiles",

        paramName: "file",
        maxFiles: 1,
        maxFilesize: 1200,
        maxFileHeight: 840,
        maxFileWidth: 840,
        acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg",           
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        parallelUploads: 1,
        renameFile: function () {
            let newname = new Date().getTime() + '_' + 'Test';
            console.log("Nombre en RenameFile:" + newname);
            return newname;
        //},

        //init: function (newname) {

            this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
```

However, some @Model.Params sent by ajax are passing "null", wich works on original filename. Im still investigating why this happend, but hope this helps the lost souls.